# Mount an Opteka 650-1300mm lens to a Nikon D3200?

Tags: nikon-d3200

My husband bought me an Opteka 650-1300mm telephoto lens for my Nikon D3200 and I can't figure out how to attach it.

Do I need to buy a lenses adaptor? Or am I just not doing it right?

Comment: Take a picture of the rear part of the lens and post it here please. I think it sometimes has a T mount, and therefore you could need an adapter.

Comment: OK give me one second

Comment: https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=10153191589082030&id=699132029

Comment: Can you upload the picture instead of linking it to Facebook? I cannot view the picture (don't have a facebook account)

Comment: Its not letting me upload anything on the app I'm on. I've been looking

Comment: Well I guess if I'd been paying attention...the mount that came with it is a t-mount. So that means I have to get an adaptor right?

Comment: Your Nikon uses a F-mount, you will indeed need an adaptor (as you suggested, the Opteka has probably a T-mount).

Answer (score 2):

That lens has a T-Mount 42mm threaded connection with a 0.75mm thread pitch. They are also called T2 mounts. M42 also have a 42mm threaded connection but with a 1mm thread pitch. (they are not interchangeable)

They often come with the T-mount adapter, but if you can't attach the lens then it either has the wrong adapter or no adapter at all.

You will need to buy a Nikon T-mount adapter that threads onto the back of the lens and allows you to mount it to a Nikon camera.  The adapter had three small set screws that allow you to rotate the mount for proper lens orientation on the camera.

[Ebay T-mounts](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Lens-Adapters-Mounts-Tubes-/30059/i.html?_from=R40&_sop=15&_nkw=t-mount%20nikon%20-telescope&rt=nc&LH_BIN=1&_trksid=p2045573.m1684)

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like the t-mount I got. But when I attached it to the camera and turned it on, it said there was no lens attached

Comment: That is normal because there is no electrical connection from the lens to the camera.

Comment: And now I can see through the lens but when I snap a pic, nothing shows up. It's all black

Comment: You will need to play with the manual settings.  The consumer grade Nikons do not meter for lenses that are not chipped.  Boost your ISO and decrease your shutter speed to start.  (You will have to workin in `M`)

Comment: You will need a stable tripod and very bright outdoor conditions to get a reasonable looking photo.